# How getConnection oci resource?

Tags: oracle, zend-framework, oracle-call-interface

I need to get the resource oci (connect). To perform the methods oci_new_descriptor, save, oci_commit and close

Code:

```
        $dbconfig = Zend_Registry::get('oci');
        $db = Zend_Db::factory('PDO_OCI', $dbconfig->config);
        $oci = $db->getConnection();
        print_r($oci);
```

**Error** - Adapter parameters must be in an array or a Zend_Config object.

Answer (score 1):

Check what type of $dbconfig, error code is pretty clear - it should be type of array or Zend_Config, but it's not

Comment: Pavel Tytyuk, $dbconfig type - Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Oci. How get Zend_Config object??

Comment: Now code is - http://paste.org.ru/?tz53ln. And error - "Configuration array must have a key for 'dbname' that names the database instance"

Comment: It expects not the adapter, it expects adapter configuration. Minimal set of option keys: dbname, username, password, host. See "db" resource configuration in config.ini